# Bootstrap: wider input field

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can I make the input field wider than the default in Twitter's Bootstrap?

I am trying to create a wider search form in the `hero-unit` class from the [example](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/hero.html).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use the bootstrap built in classes *input-large*, *input-medium*, ... : `<input type="text" class="input-large search-query">`

Or use your own css:

1. Give the element a unique classname `class="search-query input-mysize"`
2. Add this in your css file (not the bootstrap.less or css files):
   `.input-mysize { width: 150px }`

Comment: I did option #2 as the first one wasn't large enough. Any hints to make it flexible on resizing the browser? Thanks.

Comment: to make it flexible you either need javascript to listen to the resize event and adjust the width or the most easy solution: give it a relative size like '50%', '2em', ... instead of a fixed pixel size.

Comment: There's also class="input-block-level" for full-width elements - http://cssdeck.com/labs/twitter-bootstrap-full-width-contact-form

Comment: Bootstrap 3 instructs you to use grid columns to control width.
"Set heights using classes like .input-lg, and set widths using grid column classes like .col-lg-*." http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes

Comment: @PrathameshMore You might be using a newer version of bootstrap that doesn't work this way no more, check the documentation.

Answer (score 93):

### There are various classes for different size inputs

```
 :class=>"input-mini"

 :class=>"input-small"

 :class=>"input-medium"

 :class=>"input-large"

 :class=>"input-xlarge"

 :class=>"input-xxlarge"
```

Comment: Cool, didn't know about `input-xxlarge`. That does act responsively at least at some widths (I've made some responsive modifications so can't test fully).

Comment: btw you need to use this classes if you have troubles with width of input form, if you won't your input will be always wider of container size it's in

Comment: +1 for that, but these are just increasing width. How about height? Looks like there is nothing about height so i am using custom class to handle that...

Answer (score 17):

in bootstrap 3.0 :

> Set heights using classes like .input-lg, and set widths using grid column classes like .col-lg-*.

Example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-xs-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-xs-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-xs-4">
    </div>
</div>
```

Source: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes

Answer (score 9):

I made a wider input field by using either span4 or span6 as class.

```
<input type="text" class="span6 input-large search-query">
```

This way you don't need the additional custom css, mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a smaller one yet called "input-mini".

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume you were having the same issue I was. Even though you specify larger sizes for the TextBox and mark it as important, the box would not get larger. That is likely because in your site.css file the MaxWidth is being set to 280px.

Add a style attribute to your input to remove the MaxWidth like this:

```
<input type="text"  style="max-width:none !important" class="input-medium">
```

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 4, they have designed a bigger input file.

A simple solution to increase the size input file is to use `font-size`:

Add you style, for example:

```
input[type="file"] {
  font-size:35px
}
```

Otherwise, you can make one custom class and add to input control.

Comment: Welcome to SO, your answer is hard to read, could you fix the typos and grammer. You could also use the built-in syntax highlighting. Maybe take the beginners tour for learning how to use SO correctly. And wasn't the question about width and not height? How can you make an input field wider through increasing the font size?