# Bootstrap input textfield are too small?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I dont have enough points to post a picture, but I am working on a project and the input text fields are way smaller than it is on the http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html site. I have `<!DOCTYPE html>` in the application.html.erb, but it still dont work.

Anyone got any idea on what the problem might be?

Comment: Check your css rules with firebug/chrome inspector and see from which rule the `width` property is coming.

Comment: I think its coming from custom.css, but I dont know what to look for?

Answer (score 1):

The width of textbox may be affected by the parent html tag's width. I cant be sure without seeing the html mark-up. The default width is defined in bootstrap.css for input text field. You can override this width by including desired span classes to the control like this..

```
<input type="text" class="span3" />
<input type="text" class="span12" />
```

Comment: This answer is correct. By default, the widths of the input components are not 100% of the available area. If you want them to take up the entire width, use what @Kavitha-kg says and add a `class="span12"` (remember that Bootstrap uses a 12 column grid). Alternatively, you can use the input size. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784990/bootstrap-wider-input-field

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use the chrome inspector to check for the CSS rule for the input field. If that doesnt work, you can add a class or id to the input fields you need and then in a custom CSS file you can set the width of the class or id. This will change the size of your input field. Just make sure that your custom css file comes after the bootstrap css file.

Comment: This doesn't really help, because by the time you're viewing it in the browser, you've already lost information and all you'll see are specific pixel widths (e.g., width:206px), which doesn't help.